# MS Office licensing enforcement contours

Tags: microsoft-office, license-key

I tend to upgrade components of my Windows PC (the SSD in particular) and would like to know, if I were to switch to MS Office and upgrade the SSD (or the RAM):

1. Would an SSD upgrade cause a problem with Microsoft products interpreting the upgrade
   as new box and requiring a license key again?
2. Assuming Microsoft products thought it was a different PC
   and I entered the original license key,
   should I expect to clear the activation hurdle?

## EXAMPLE ISSUE

Office 2011 demanded an activation key
when I upgraded a friend's Apple OS X computer to an SSD drive.

Comment: What do you mean by "box"? If you replace SSD probably need to install windows on it, which also means need to enter key. How Office is related to the problem?

Comment: When I replace the SSD I do not need to install windows.  It is ghosted over with Apricorn

Comment: Box is slang for a desktop PC

Comment: Some of the confusion here is due to the fact that you've asked two different questions, one about Windows, another about Office. The change in hardware might make Office insist on seeing the activation key again. Best case, you'll give the key, it'll reactivate. Worst case, you'll need to call MS to get it sorted, using the number the activation request gives you.  I can't say what'll happen with Windows.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I'll change Office \ Windows to Microsoft.  It is constructive when actionable feedback is provided.  Wondering now if this correction will move the question off the 'put on hold' list?

Answer (score 1):

You only need a new license when you change your motherboard and/or CPU. So, adding a new SSD won't affect you at all.

Comment: I hope that is correct and the example cited with Mac OSX only helps on that platform